# Not able to run shell script in Mac's Automator

Tags: macos, automator

Hi so I have this ffmpeg command to run in Mac's Automator app:

```
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy "${f%.mp4}"-new.mp4; done
```

I created a new workflow in automator receives movie files, get folder contents, and then "Run Shell script"

In the shell script window I added the following:

```
for f in *.mp4; do /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy "${f%.mp4}"-new.mp4; done
```

But an error message shows up "*.mp4" no such file or directory.

What am I doing wrong here? Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: I fixed this probem but it's giving another error:      Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp42
    creation_time   : 2019-02-09T13:5

Comment: Ok these are ffmpeg output messages. Is there anyway automator can be set to not  display these messages? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing the whole workflow.  The error seems to indicate that the script may be at fault though.

You need to have the shell to /bin/bash, and pass input to "as arguments."  Your for line may need to be `for f in "$@"` or something similar as "$@" should be the passed argument.

Comment: That should be `for f in "$@"` to make it operate on *all* passed files (and the double-quotes are needed in case file paths/names contain spaces). Compare with the original: `for f in *.mp4` will try to operate on all .mp4 files in the "current working directory", which by default is your home folder -- probably not what you wanted at all.